# HttpUrlConnection Запрос на веб сервис 1с с логином с android

Tags: android, запрос, веб-сервер, 1с, httpurlconnection

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я сделал запрос на веб сервис 1с, в нём есть окошко авторизации, как мне отправить логин и пароль вместе с запросом? 
Есть ли какой-то метод для передачи логина и пароля?

```
             httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(1000);
            httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(1000);
            httpURLConnection.connect();
```

Comment: Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
     protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
       return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
     }
   });   Нашёл в документации эту конструкцию, через неё можно как-нибудь авторизоваться?

Comment: Вам нужно посмотреть как это происходит в браузере. Скорее всего там не GET, но POST запрос. Скорее всего логин/пароль передаются параметрами запроса. Не знаю как через HttpURLConnection это сделать, но в сети есть примеры. Советую лучше использовать OkHttp библиотеку. Также вам надо не забыть про разрешение на интернет для приложения и не забыть делать это не в основном потоке.

Answer (score 1):

```
    String userpass = username + ":" + password;
    String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(userpass.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

    httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(1000);
    httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(1000);
    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", auth);
    httpURLConnection.connect();
```